# Did the Erev rav had a role in the complaints of Bamidbar 14?

Tags: commentaries, parashat-shelach

The עֵרֶב רַב is often connected to the הָאסַפְסֻף and often described by our sages as a group among the Israelites which caused and initiated a lot of the complaints made by the people.

Did this group also lifted up their voice in the verses of Bamidbar 14?;
And if so did have some part in this complaint did they also died as a consequence thereof during the forty years in the wilderness?

Comment: I'm not following your question. In the 1st paragraph, it seems that you have asserted that they did.

Comment: @DanF Well I was asking because Joshua 5 also talks about this group, these men of war, and I wondered if the erev rav was a part of this group also. But because Joshua 5 is a consequence of Bamidbar 14 I wanted to know this first, before asking other questions.

Comment: You should probably copy that into your question body, and, ideally, provide a link to the specific verse you're referring to. Without the specific verse, it becomes harder to determine your assumption, esp. since the only verse that I know that uses the term *Erev Rav* is the one in parshat *Bo*.

Comment: I'm speculating - Do you mean Joshua 5:5 when it mentions that all the people of the desert generation died in the desert? Are you asking if the *erev rav* members were included?

Comment: @DanF verse 6: ..till all the nation, the men of war that came forth out of Egypt, were consumed.. And yes I wondered if the erev rav or members thereof were included or not. But after I read Bamidbar 26:4 I doubted.

Comment: @DanF, but if they were not included that would mean that only the Israelites hungered back to Egypt here in Bamidbar 14, and would rather have died there or in the wilderness.

Comment: @DanF If you're able would you please see if you could give an answer to this related question? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90858/erev-rav-the-people-of-the-children-of-israel